# NSMutableAttributedString Italic and Bold do not work at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to italicized and bold an `NSMutableAttributedString`, I tried some combinations but only one attribute works.

```
[attributedText addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:boldTextFontSize]}
                        range:range3];
```

and

```
[attributedText addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14]}
                        range:range3];
[attributedText addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:boldTextFontSize]}
                        range:range3];
```

Only one of them is applied to the string. Is there a practical way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

A font file contains all displayable characters, but in only one (!) style. To show a bold-italic font, you will have to load a file that contains bold-italic symbols.

You can not load 2 font files and expect the OS to mix them up...

If there is no bold-italic font, you need to use a custom font.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how can I use a custom font ?